# Android- onTouchListener doesnt want to work with OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I want to put onTouchListener on my parent View and onLongClickListener on my child views, it looks like this

```
for(int i=0;i<(boardSize*boardSize);i++){
        if(i%boardSize==0){
            layout=new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            parentLayout.addView(layout);

        }
        imageViews.add(new ImageView(this));
        imageViews.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.tiles);
        imageViews.get(i).setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        imageViews.get(i).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this , v);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch(item.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.flag:
                                ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.flag_icon);
                                break;
                            case R.id.question:
                                break;
                            case R.id.clear:
                                break;

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        String tileID = "tile_"+i;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(tileID, "id", getPackageName());
        imageViews.get(i).setId(resID);
        layout.addView(imageViews.get(i));
        isViewDiscovered[i]=false;


    }
    parentLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
            LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)v;

            for(int i=0;i<layout.getChildCount();i++){
                LinearLayout horizontalLayout=(LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(i);
                for(int j=0;j<horizontalLayout.getChildCount();j++){
                    ImageView view=(ImageView) horizontalLayout.getChildAt(j);
                    Rect outRect=new Rect(view.getLeft(),view.getTop(),view.getRight(),view.getBottom());

                    if(!isViewDiscovered[j+10*i]) {

                        if (outRect.contains((int) event.getX() - horizontalLayout.getLeft(), (int) event.getY() - horizontalLayout.getTop())) {
                            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.r1);
                        } else {
                            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiles);
                        }
                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && outRect.contains((int) event.getX() - horizontalLayout.getLeft(), (int) event.getY() - horizontalLayout.getTop())) {
                            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.r2);
                            isViewDiscovered[j+10*i]=true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

It doesnt work as intended tho. Im just getting the clicks inputs in, but the touch events dont happen. When i cut off the clicklistener the touchListener works just fine. Also when i jump into debugger, when i step into parentLayout.setOnClickListener it tells me parentLayout=No such instance field:'parentLayout' even tho it was defined above and used multiple times.
Thanks for all help